# How do I use IF THEN ELSE to SELECT and INSERT or UPDATE Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've been trying to use the following query

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1) 
THEN 
    (INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES (2, user2)) 
ELSE 
    (UPDATE users SET username = 'userUpdated')
```

But I keep getting

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES (2)) ELSE (UPDATE users SET id = 11)' at line 1 */
```

Also tried using the following query

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1) 
THEN 
    (SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 1) 
ELSE 
    (INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES (1, 'user'))
```

But this time I got

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE 
(INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES (1, 'user'))' at line 4 */
```

Am I doing or understood something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` *statement* can only be used in programming blocks, such as stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

In any case, MySQL offers simpler syntax for this functionality:  `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.

To use it, `id` must have a unique index, unique constraint, or be defined as the primary key.  Let me assume that a column so-named is already so-defined.

Then:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username)
    VALUES (2, user2)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username = 'userUpdated';
```

Comment: So, The second statement`[SELECT else INSERT]` can't be applied?

Comment: @Toleo . . . This statement handles both conditions.

Comment: But which is better for performance? `SELECT` first then `INSERT` or as you did here `INSERT` then `SELECT` on duplicated key?

Comment: @Toleo . . . A single statement with the appropriate index is going to be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the END IF (and semi colons)?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1) 
    THEN 
    (SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = 1);
ELSE 
    (INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES (1, 'user'));
END IF;
```

Comment: Still gave me the same problem

Comment: As Toleo suggested, it's only possible to use this construct in programming blocks

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1) 
begin

    INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES (2, 'user2')
    end
ELSE 
    UPDATE users SET username = 'userUpdated'
```

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB 10.1 and newer, you can use compound statements outside of stored procedures. [This blog post](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/atomic-compound-statements) gives a good description of what you can do with it.

Here's an example the blog:

```
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN  
   ROLLBACK;
   RESIGNAL;
  END;

  START TRANSACTION;

    stmt1;
    ....
    stmtN;

  COMMIT;
END
```